# Как делаются такие переменные?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

В некоторых CMS в HTML можно писать типа так: `<span>{version src="/css/style.css}</span>` или же вот так `{get_post}` так вот, как такое делается, как такое вообще называется? Не могу найти в гугле, т.к. не знаю, как такое правильно загуглить. В чьи-та cms не хочу лесть, хочу чтобы где-то объяснили и показали это.

Comment: просто некий шаблон, который можно распарсить и подставить свои данные.  т.е. потом движок парсит всё что между `{` и `}` и подставляет туда что-то

Comment: А есть какая-то статья об этом? Хочу почитать и посмотреть примеры)

Answer (score 0):

такие вставки называются Плейсхолдеры, специальные функции, шаблонизаторы, подменяют такой Плейсхолдер результатом выполнения функций внутри него

Comment: Спасибо, нашёл!